# jquery ui sortable: how to drop into nested container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html structure

```
 <div class="wrapper-all">
     <div class="wrapper-left">
         <div class="row-left">
             <div class="item-left">A</div>
         </div>
         <div class="row-left">
             <div class="item-left">B</div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="wrapper-right">
         <div class="item-right">Firstname</div>
         <div class="item-right">Salutation</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

The goal is to move single div element (.item-right) from wrapper-right to wrapper-left into div container .row-left. If I move element Firstname with the mouse to element A, element Firstname should be dropped to element a's  parent (.row-left).

I tried the following approach:

```
$(".wrapper-right, .wrapper-left").sortable({
  connectWith: ".wrapper-left",
  appendTo: ".row-left"
})
```

But this will not work. How can I achieve the goal?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking. Can update the post with some more details? And/or share some more code https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve